# Does this graph have a special name? (8-connected neighborhood)

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Does this graph have a special name?

The vertices are arranged on a square square grid with a side length of $n$ and each inner vertices has an edge to its 8 neighbors.

And what about a similar graph with vertices arranged on a $n \times m$ rectangular grid?

[image: Ruzzle™ graph]

Comment: it looks like the union of Cartesian product and the categorical product of two paths

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [King's graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_graph).  For all your Kingly needs.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of graph products the $n \times m$ grid will be the [strong product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs) of the path graphs $P_n$ and $P_m$, usually written as $P_n \boxtimes P_m$.